# how can i change the format of datetime that django is sending to frontend?

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

model.py

```
class DateTest(models.Model):
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

view.py

```
def getdate(request):
     dates = DateTest.objects.filter(product=pid).values('date_created')
     da=list(dates)
     print(da)
     return JsonResponse({'reviews':da})
```

Expected output:

```
[{ 'date_created': datetime.datetime(May 1, 2021, 5:37 p.m.)}]
```

Actual output:

```
[{'date_reviewed': datetime.datetime(2021, 5, 1, 13, 2, 12, 404779, tzinfo=<UTC>)}]
```

Comment: have a look at django template filters using the date filter to format the datetime objects https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/templates/builtins/#date

Comment: If you're returning a `JsonResponse` you'll need to format it as a string using [`strftime()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strftime).

Comment: @elyas where should I add strtime() I can't add this to dates or da as I am returning other data also my bad that code is not complete but you can that as there multiple values and I only want to change the date_created.it will something look like this `dates = DateTest.objects.filter(product=pid).values('date_created','name', 'address')
     da=list(dates)
     print(da)`

Comment: @Codebug i am trying to return a json response so template filtering has no use

Answer (score 0):

you should try this code to convert your date format

## Formatting datetime

date.strftime("%B %d, %Y, %I:%M%p")